# How to include UserID and Password in the http header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, header, http-headers

```
            string requestPath = "http://host/user/register";

            string RegJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userProfile);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestPath);
            request.Headers.Add("UserID:"+ userID +";");
            request.Headers.Add("Password:" + password + ";");
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Method = "POST";
```

Here userprofile i am converting to json and use that for the webrequest call. After registration and login, i need to include userID and password in the header for every request. I'm not sure weather I am passing UserID & Password properly in the header or not.

IT SHOULD APPEAR AS BELOW IN HEADER:

POST /MyURL/ HTTP/1.1 
Host    hostname 
Content-Length  396 
Origin  chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn 
UserID        12345 
Password        98765abc 
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0  
 
AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11 
Content-Type    application/json 
Accept  */* 
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch 
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.

I tried   request.Headers.Add("UserID:"+ userID_Value +";");

Comment: Are you talking about BAsic Http authentication?

Comment: Why do you need the user id and password passed on every request? Need more background on what you are trying to do, but as a rule of thumb, passing around the pasword like that to a non ssl connection is a BAD idea.

Comment: Maybe you just need `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);`

Comment: request.Credentials makes it bad request. I need to add UserID and Password in restful service for all the request so it should appear with request in the header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need semicolon in the web request, you just need to add as a string.

```
               request.Headers.Add("UserID", userID);            
               request.Headers.Add("Password", password);
```